# Reliable instruction on installing Ubuntu on Macbook Pro

Tags: install, unix, dual-boot

There are some walk-through kind of instruction on installing Ubuntu on Macbook Pro (as dual boot OS along with Mac OS X), such as [Lifehacker's post](http://lifehacker.com/5934942/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-mac-and-take-back-your-powerhouse-apple-hardware).  But they are either too old that I worry if the particular details are still currently applicable, or the source is not particularly reliable.  Any pointer to a good, reliable, and current source on this?  I intend to install Ubuntu as a dual boot OS on my Macbook Pro (mid 2011 model).

Answer (score 2):

I think the following link will help you : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Detailed_How-To

Here they have explained it very clearly:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/dual-boot-os-ubuntu

Hope this will help you.